# How to use Firestore in Nuxt3 with SSR?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt RC8 combined with Firestore.

My goal is to make the firestore request SSR and then combine it with Firestore's `onSnapshot` to get realtime updates after hydration is done.

I have created this composable `useAssets`:

```js
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';
import { Asset, RandomAPI, RandomDatabase } from '@random/api';

/**
 * Asset basic composable
 * @param dbClient Database client
 * @param options Extra options, like live data binding
 */
export function useAssets(dbClient: RandomDatabase) {
  const assets = ref([]);
  const unsubscribe = ref(null);
  const searchQuery = ref('');
  const randomAPI = RandomAPI.getInstance();

  async function fetchAssets(options?: { live: boolean }): Promise<void> {
    if (options?.live) {
      try {
        const query = randomAPI.fetchAssetsLive(dbClient, (_assets) => {
          assets.value = _assets as Asset<any>[];
        });
        unsubscribe.value = query;
      } catch (error) {
        throw Error(`Error reading assets: ${error}`);
      }
    } else {
      const query = await randomAPI.fetchAssetsStatic(dbClient);
      assets.value = query;
    }
  }

  const filteredAssets = computed(() => {
    return searchQuery.value
      ? assets.value.filter((asset) =>
          asset.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.value.toLowerCase())
        )
      : assets.value;
  });

  function reverseAssets(): void {
    const newArray = [...assets.value];
    assets.value = newArray.reverse();
  }

  return {
    assets,
    fetchAssets,
    filteredAssets,
    searchQuery,
    reverseAssets,
    unsubscribe,
  };
}
```

The `randomAPI.fetchAssetsLive` comes from the firestore queries file:

```js
export function fetchAssetsLive({
  db,
  callback,
  options,
}: {
  db: Firestore;
  callback: (
    assets: Asset<Timestamp>[] | QueryDocumentSnapshot<Asset<Timestamp>>[]
  ) => void;
  options?: { fullDocs: boolean };
}): Unsubscribe {
  const assetCollection = collection(db, 'assets') as CollectionReference<
    Asset<Timestamp>
  >;

  if (options?.fullDocs) {
    return onSnapshot(assetCollection, (querySnapshot) =>
      callback(querySnapshot.docs)
    );
  }

  // Return unsubscribe
  return onSnapshot(assetCollection, (querySnapshot) =>
    callback(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
  );
}
```

And then the component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to Random!</h1>
    <Button @click="reverseAssets">Reverse order</Button>
    <ClientOnly>
      <!-- <Input name="search" label="Search for an asset" v-model="searchQuery" /> -->
    </ClientOnly>
    <ul>
      <li class="list-item" v-for="asset in assets" :key="asset.name">
        Asset Name: {{ asset.name }} Type: {{ asset.type }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Button, Input } from '@random/ui';
import { useNuxtApp, useAsyncData } from '#app';

const { $randomFirebase, $firestore, $getDocs, $collection } = useNuxtApp();

const { fetchAssets, filteredAssets, searchQuery, reverseAssets, assets } =
  useAssets($randomFirebase);

// const a = process.client ? filteredAssets : assets;

onMounted(() => {
  // console.log(searchQuery.value);
  // fetchAssets({ live: true });
});

watch(
  assets,
  (val) => {
    console.log('watcher: ', val);
  },
  { deep: true, immediate: true }
);

// TODO: make SSR work
await useAsyncData(async () => {
  await fetchAssets();
});
</script>
```

Why is it only loading via SSR and then `assets.value` goes `[]`? Refreshing the page retrieves renders the items correctly but then once hydration comes in, it's gone.

Querying both, in `onMounted` and `useAsyncData`, makes it send correctly via SSR the values, makes it work client-side too but there is still a hydration missmatch, even being the values the same. And visually you only see the ones from the client-side request, not the SSR.

Is there a better approach? What am I not understanding?

I don't want to use firebase-admin as the SSR query maker because I want to use roles in the future (together with Firebase Auth via sessions).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the hydration issue in two ways:

1. By displaying in the template only specific information, since JS objects are not ordered by default so there could be different order between the SSR query and the CS query.
2. By ordering by a field name in the query.
3. By making sure that the `serverData` is displayed until first load of the `onsnapshot` is there, so theres is not a mismatch this way: [data] -> [] -> [data]. For now I control it in the template in a very cheap way but it was for testing purposes:

```
<li class="list-item" v-for="asset in (isServer || (!isServer && !assets.length) ? serverData : assets)" :key="asset.name">
  Asset Name: {{ asset.name }} Type: {{ asset.type }}
</li>
```

4. By using `/server/api/assets.ts` file with this:

```js
import { getDocs, collection, query, orderBy, CollectionReference, Timestamp, Query } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { Asset } from '@random/api/dist';
import { firestore } from '../utils/firebase';

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const assetCollection = collection(firestore, 'assets');

  let fullQuery: CollectionReference<Asset<Timestamp>> | Query<Asset<Timestamp>>;
  try {
    // @ts-ignore
    fullQuery = query(assetCollection, orderBy('name'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    // @ts-ignore
    fullQuery = assetCollection;
  }

  const ref = await getDocs(fullQuery);

  return ref.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
});
```

And then in the component, executing:

```js
const { data: assets } = useFetch('/api/assets');
onMounted(async () => {
  fetchAssets({ live: true });
});
```

Still, if I try via `useAsyncData` it does not work correctly.